# Can I see if coordinate A is within 50 meters of coordinate B using Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, gps, coordinates, google-latitude

**Problem**

I have two coordinates: A B

**Solution?**

Can I see if coordinate A is within 50 meters of coordinate B using Google Maps API?

**Other Solution?**

If not, is there a way to do this without using google API?

Comment: Not sure why the -1, but for the answerers thanks :) Its easily done then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[computeDistanceBetween()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) from the Google Maps API v3 geometry library returns the straight line distance between two google.maps.LatLng objects (the default units are meters).

Be sure to [include the geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries)

Answer (score 1):

Each phone, amd many other geo apis have a function to calculate the distance between two lat,lon coordinates.

If you dont have one, then use the haversine distance formula.